# Failing to copy content of a file into another using operator overloading

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to copy contents of one file into another by overloading "=" operator.
I want to do something like when i write, file2 = file1 , the contents of file1 will be written into file2.
But my code fails to do so.
This is what i have done so far.

```
class EasyFile{
    std::string fileContent;
    char* filePath;
public:
    EasyFile(char* filePath){
       this->filePath = filePath;
       std::fstream file(filePath);
       getline(file,fileContent);
    }
    char* getFilePath(){
        return filePath;
    }
    std::string getFileContent(){
        return fileContent;
    }
    void setContent(std::string content,char* filePath){
        std::ofstream file(filePath);
        file<<content;
    }
    void operator=(EasyFile f);
 };
void EasyFile::operator=(EasyFile f){
   this->setContent(f.getFileContent(),f.getFilePath());
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
 {
   EasyFile efile1(argv[1]);
   EasyFile efile2(argv[2]);
   efile2 = efile1;
   std::string output="";
   std::ifstream file(argv[2]);
   std::getline(file,output);
   std::cout<<output;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `main()` return anything? Also, assignment operator overloads should return a reference to the object getting the assignment.

Comment: @owacoder It's not necessary to let `main()` return, it defaults to `exit(0);`.

Comment: That's true, but it's good practice to `return` values from functions that are defined to return a value!

Comment: @owacoder you are right bout int main().But it is not always necessary for an operator overload to return a value. I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: Neither of my comments were intended to analyze bugs. There isn't *technically* anything wrong with those two things. The code would work just fine (in those respects) without changing them. I was just giving hints for better programming technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the following line in your function `setContent`:

```
std::ofstream file(filePath);
```

The variable `filepath` used is the one passed as argument (the origin path not the destination path). You are trying to do a copy from origin to origin.

Comment: A good argument for decorating your member variables in some manner (flavor to taste)

Comment: Woho!  that worked! Thank you!
Well that was a serious mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I can see several problems in the code you provided:

1. In method setContent the filePath parameter is hiding the member filePath because they have the same name. As it is the method is opening the file given by the filePath parameter (not the file represented by this) and writing the value of parameter content. What you want to do is remove the filePath parameter altogether. This way it will write content to the file represented by this.
2. In the constructor, when you call getline you are not reading the whole content of the file, your are only reading the first line. To read the whole content you should do an iteration reading lines and appending them to your string. You can do that with code like this:

   ```
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>

   #define BUFF_SIZE 512

   std::string ReadFile(const char* fileName)
   {
     std::string ret;
     std::ifstream ifs(fileName);
     char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
     do {
       ifs.read(buff, BUFF_SIZE);
       ret.append(buff, ifs.gcount());
     } while (!ifs.eof());

     return ret;
   }
   ```
3. This is not critical to what you are trying to do but it's good to keep it in mind. In the assignment operator it is a good idea to pass the argument by const reference (const EasyFile& file instead of just EasyFile). You will need to mark your getter methods as const by appending the keyword const at the end of the signature and before the opening brace.